# how to make "vertical text div" in bootstrap grid with size col-2 (other col-10 are in use). which is also centered it self as the row expanse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to print one-word let say "whatever" and print it in the last column that is col-2; VERTICALLY. 
Which is also centered in that column (col-2) from all the way and responsive to stay in the center of the row whole the time.

from the image: I want to print a word vertically in one or 2 line, size (col-2)

### another side- size is col-12

|            col-10                        | col-2 |
   |                                          |       |

### |                                          |       |

Comment: I am not able to add image

Comment: Could you please add the code you have tried.